# Do video cards store any personal information? Should they be destroyed when getting rid of them?

Tags: hardware

I realize this question sounds a bit ridiculous but I figured it couldn't really hurt to ask.  I am in the process of getting rid of some old computers of mine, and I know that I need to destroy the hard drives.

With this in mind, I also need to get rid of an AMD Radeon graphics card that came with a Dell PC I bought in 2012.  It's quite large and the thought crossed my mind- could this also contain some of my personal information? Do I need to destroy this along with my old hard drives?

Comment: In theory, graphic cards have a BIOS which could persist data. However, this is unlikely to be a practical concern for data exfiltration.

Answer (score 5):

No, video cards don't retain any personal information. You can get rid of them without problems.

Hard drives are **made to store information**, so you need to properly dispose them. Video cards are not information storage devices, so all information they have are related to their jobs, and its most firmware. They don't store anything else.